Ruff and E203 rule
I'm having some issue with string slicing, ruff is formatting such code:
result: str
custom_index = 5
result = (
        result[:custom_index]
        + f"new_value"
        + result[custom_index + 7:]
)

and makes last line having extra whitespace result[custom_index + 7 :].
But there is another rule PEP 8: E203 whitespace before ':'.
How can I disable such behaviour? I've tried to add some rules to exclude in pyproject.toml, but my guessing failed.
Here is a test project to reproduce the error. Launch pre-commit run --all-files and see custom_file_from_project.py line 12 and line 17.

I would also complain. + has spaces and : with lower priority not, so mind may parse 7: as an entity. Parenthesis may help but still ugly (and why not using one single f-string with the 3 parts? -- But this is about my aesthetic, not the answer of the real question (about ruff).

I can't reproduce the problem with ruff check --select E203 --preview (0.7.2). What version of Ruff are you using?

@InSync - v0.6.0

@InSync - got the same behaviour on 0.7.2. If you can't reproduce the problem (btw, thanks for your time), I will create an empty project and try to reproduce the error there and add the github link to the question

Like @InSync I cannot reproduce.  It makes me wonder what your ruff configuration looks like.

@InSync - added a github link to the question, feel free to lock. Thanks in advance for your time

@MarcelWilson - added a github link to the question, feel free to lock. Thanks in advance for your time

Are you using ruff format or ruff check?  Because ruff format works nearly identical to black in that you have almost no control over how it formats things.
The only way around that is to use # fmt: off and # fmt: on

@MarcelWilson - Thanks for the info about fmt. Regarding ruff format: I removed tool.ruff.format section from pyproject.toml, but ruff stills makes same changes with : and []

My bad, I also removed ruff format from pre-commit config. But this is just removing, not ignoring the rule

Yeah, if you're using ruff to format your code, you wont have much control (if any) over how it does the formatting.  Like Black, it is very opinionated.  It's all or nothing.
